# Do Facebook API Settings allow developer only access?

Tags: ruby, facebook, api

I am working on an app in ruby using:koala:omniauth

When I click share to wall from the application it allows me to share and
changes my permission accordingly. When I use an account that is not setup as a developer it sends 200 error "permissions not provided." but does not ask for "permissions" like it did with the account connected to facebook developer.

Is there a setting somewhere on Facebook developer that controls this?
I would like all users to be re-asked the permission and not just developers of the app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#review

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to ask Facebook to review the app for special permissions..